# Running multiple queries in nodejs mysql async/await

Tags: node.js, async-await

I am new in nodejs.
I want to run multiple queries in a function which dependent each other.

```
pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
        let productDetailsQuery = "select * from products where id = ?";
        connection.query(productDetailsQuery, [event.product_id], (error, products) => {
            if (products.length) {
                connection.query("select * from galleries where product_id = ?", [products[0].id], (err, galleries ) => {
                    products[0].customAttributes = galleries ;
                });
                connection.query("select * from custom_attributes where product_id = ?", [products[0].id], (err, custom_attributes) => {
                    products[0].customAttributes = custom_attributes;
                });
                connection.query("select * from sizes where product_id = ?", [products[0].id], (err, sizes ) => {
                    products[0].sizes= sizes;
                });

                .............................
                //more queries to run here and to append to products result.
                ................................

                console.log({
                    status: true,
                    message: "Product found.",
                    data: products
                })
            } else {
                console.log({
                    status: false,
                    message: "Products is not found",
                    data: [
                        "Product is not found for id : " + event.product_id
                    ]
                })
            }
        });
    })
```

When I console my products , its showing only the first querie's result. it is not showing the inner querie's result.
if I console inside the inner queries, I can get the desired output.

Please help me to achieve this.

My desired output is

```
{ 
 status:true,
 message : "product found",
 data : [{
     "id" :12,
     "product_name":"bat",
     "galleries": [......],
     "customAttributes":[.......',
     "sizes":[..........]
 }]

}
```

NOTE: I DONT WANT TO RUN QUERIES IN CALLBACK OF ONE ANOTHER

Comment: Please check my answer and correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 0):

I got one answer,
I am not sure how much correct it is.
anybody can review my answer and tell the corrections.
Thank you.
THe answer is

```
pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
        let productDetailsQuery = "select * from products where id = ?";
        connection.query(productDetailsQuery, [event.product_id],async  (error, products) => {
            if (products.length) {
                sql = "select * from custom_attributes where product_id = ?";
                args = [products[0].id];
                await util.promisify( connection.query ).call( connection, sql, args ).then((custom_attributes)=>{
                    products[0].customAttributes = custom_attributes;
                });

                sql = "select * from galleries where product_id = ?";
                args = [products[0].id];
                await util.promisify( connection.query ).call( connection, sql, args ).then((galleries)=>{
                    products[0].galleries = galleries;
                });

                sql = "select * from ratings where product_id = ?";
                args = [products[0].id];
                await util.promisify( connection.query ).call( connection, sql, args ).then((ratings)=>{
                    products[0].ratings = ratings;
                });

                sql = "select * from comments where product_id = ?";
                args = [products[0].id];
                await util.promisify( connection.query ).call( connection, sql, args ).then((comments)=>{
                    products[0].comments = comments;
                });
                console.log({
                    status: true,
                    message: "Product found.",
                    data: products[0]
                })
                process.exit()
            } else {
                console.log({
                    status: false,
                    message: "Products is not found",
                    data: [
                        "Product is not found for id : " + event.product_id
                    ]
                })
            }
        });
    })
```

Need to import

```
const util = require('util');
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because of the async behaviour of your code
there is couple of ways to handle it
1) callback --> I don't like it
2) async-await

we can write this code in this way

```
pool.getConnection(async (err, connection) => {
        let productDetailsQuery = "select * from products where id = ?";
        let products = await executeQuery(connection,productDetailsQuery, [event.product_id]);            
    if (products.length) {

                .............................
                   //more queries to run here and to append to products result.
                ................................

                console.log({
                    status: true,
                    message: "Product found.",
                    data: products
                })
            } else {
                console.log({
                    status: false,
                    message: "Products is not found",
                    data: [
                        "Product is not found for id : " + event.product_id
                    ]
                })
            }
        });
    });

async function executeQuery(connection, query, parameters) {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       connection.query(query, parameters, (error, response) 
       => {
            if(error) return reject(error);
            return resolve(response);
       })
   })
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
const util = require('util');

pool.getConnection(async (err, connection) => {

    connection.query = util.promisify(connection.query);

    let productDetailsQuery = "select * from products where id = ?";
    let products = await onnection.query(productDetailsQuery, [event.product_id]);
    if (products.length) {
        let galleries = await connection.query("select * from galleries where product_id = ?", [products[0].id]);
        products[0].customAttributes = galleries;

        let custom_attributes = await connection.query("select * from custom_attributes where product_id = ?", [products[0].id]);
        products[0].customAttributes = custom_attributes;

        let sizes = await connection.query("select * from sizes where product_id = ?", [products[0].id]);
        products[0].sizes = sizes;

        //.............................
        //more queries to run here and to append to products result.
        //................................

        console.log({
            status: true,
            message: "Product found.",
            data: products
        })
    } else {
        console.log({
            status: false,
            message: "Products is not found",
            data: [
                "Product is not found for id : " + event.product_id
            ]
        })
    }
})
```